# HTML - how do i enable counter-reset increment to continue in table next page?

Tags: html, typescript, angular-ui-bootstrap

im currently using html counter-reset for my serial numbers in a table. (angular + bootstrap)

for my table, im using pagination of 5 items per page. so ideally, the serial numbers should be 1-5 in page1, 6-10 in page2 etc.

currently, when i switch to page2 in the table, the serial number resets back to 1-5. i think this is due to the action in click next page is calling the function to load the 2nd page of the table which is resetting everything again.

how do i implement it to auto continue from the previous page serial number which is 5 in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Without your current code we cant help you. So try to implement some code in your question!